# Scrollbar in JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Just wondering if anyone know how to implement a vertical scrollbar that spans the entire scene in JavaFX? Been trying to figure it out for a few days now and I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You could use an HBox to separate the Scrollbar and the rest of your content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean make it your root you can do it like this

```
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();
    TextField yourcontent = new TextField("this is an example");
    pane.setContent(yourcontent);
    pane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane,300,300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.showAndWait();
```

and then put the rest of your content in it via setContent();

Comment: THANK YOU AUSTIN, didn't realize you could pass the scroll pane into the Scene constructor. My screen works as desired now, appreciate it :). (Now back to figuring out the back end stuff haha.)